# Detecting Office addin host without including office.js

Tags: javascript, office365-apps, office-js

In our webapp, we would like to be able to show different content at the same URL based on the host from which the site is opened. E.g https://localhost:44300 will behave differently depending on if it is opened from within a browser or an office js taskpane.

While that is the case, we would like not to include the office.js javascript until we know that the website is accessed from within an office js taskpane. Therefore it is also not possible to use `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported`.

The way we do it at the moment is by looking at the URL since it includes the `_host_Info`. As an example we make the following check right now

```
if(window.location.search.indexOf('_host_Info=Word') > -1) { /* initiate app for word js addin */ }
```

Even though this works, it doesn't seem to be a good solution - especially if we want to navigate to other pages on the website. We therefore hope that there could be another way that the Office js host could be detected without having to include Office.js script beforehand

Comment: we are evaluating adding an API to detect host ("Excel, Word, Outlook, etc) & platform (Desktop, Mac, Web, etc) info. To make sure we're taking it into account, would you mind describing the particular use-cases you are facing, that led you to seek this API? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Michael! We are building the SaaS [Templafy](http://templafy.com) that runs in both web, VSTO and Office Web Add-ins. We will be happy to show you our solution and the use-cases that we are facing! Please contact me by email on osk@templafy.com

Comment: Thanks, Oskar. That sounds intriguing indeed, even hostInfo discussion aside. Let me pass on your contact info to a colleague, Sudhi, and see if he wants to reach out to you guys at some point (though please don't feel ignored if he doesn't immediately do that).

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you describe is not supported -- and truthfully, I wonder how often it is that you want to use the exact same site both as an Office add-in and a standalone website. What we've most often seen is that people will re-use some of the same common libraries and CSS, but have different html pages for each scenario.

Note, too, that when run as an Office add-in, the page must include a reference to Office.initialize. This again makes it hard to re-use the same website contents for both an add-in and a standalone site.  So my recommendation would be to refactor and share what you can, but have 2 separate html presences.

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: I'm currently using publishing a plugin that works for several platforms including office (but just in mac) because window.opener doesn't work in windows... I'm trying to use office-js but I'm falling in this exact user case... it should work on every single context, but just because decided to limit that functionality, I cant make it work for both...

Comment: @Hamdan, I have left the Office Extensibility team some time ago. If you're running into an issue, suggest you create a new question, to make sure that it gets adequate visibility...